Save adequate version of ContourPlot without artifacts and of small size: rasterization does not work
Consider this code used in Mathematica 13.2:
r1f[x_, y_] = 0.001/y x^-3
form[x_] := 
 ReplaceAll[x, {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 2]}]
pt = ContourPlot[r1f[x, y], {x, 0.211, 0.95}, {y, 0.01, 20}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotPoints -> 200, 
  ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> 
   Log[{0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5}], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[18, Black], 
  PlotRange -> {{0.211, 0.95}, {0.01, 20}, {10^-5., 6.}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {10^-5, 6}}, {0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 
      0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 13], 
     LegendFunction -> form, LegendMarkerSize -> 500, 
     LegendLabel -> 
      Placed["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(1\)]\)", Right]], Below], 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log", "Log"}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(1\)]\)"}], 20, Thick, 
    Black]]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "plot.pdf"}], pt, 
 "AllowRasterization" -> True]

It saves the plot in the form of an unrasterized object, with artifacts and large size of the file, independently of whether I am using the option "AllowRasterization" -> True:

Could you please tell me how to fix this issue, producing a good quality .pdf with a significantly smaller size?

Does first exporting to PNG and then to PDF solves your problem? Export["plot.png", pt]; Export["plot.pdf", Import["plot.png"]] You can also specify ImageSize when exporting PNG.

@azerbajdzan : I prefer keeping the quality as high as possible. I am not sure that using this way would maintain it. Also, my final document will be .pdf, and I would like to preserve the vector form as long as possible.

Please use search before posting a new question. This particular issue has been mentioned several times on this SE.
